# A simple C switch statement program error. I cant build and run it. I don't know why

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm new to C an programming and I'm trying a piece of code from a book.
When I try to build and run it, I get errors and warnings that unable me to run the program.
Not sure why. My code is written verbatim. I'm also using codeBlocks for PC.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     char choice;
     printf("Are you filing a single, joint or ");  
     printf("Married return (s, j, m)? ");  
     do
     {
         scanf(" %c ", &choice);
         switch (choice)
         { 
             case ('s') : printf("You get a $1,000 deduction.\n");
                    break;
             case ('j') : printf("You geta 1 $3,000 deduction.\n");
                    break;
             case ('m') : printf("You geta $5,000 deduction.\n");
                    break;

             default    : printf("I don't know the ");
                          printf("option %c.\n, choice");
                          printf("Try again.\n");
                    break;

         }
      }while ((choice != 's') && (choice != 'j') && (choice != 'm');  
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: What errors and warnings are you getting?

Comment: Also, the line `scanf(" %c, &choice");` doesn't look right - are you sure the quotation mark is in the right spot?

Comment: When passing arguments to `printf` or `scanf` they are not placed inside the quotation marks. You want something like `scanf(" %c", &choice);`

Comment: You're right Thegrinner I had to edit the quotation... The other errors are C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\c++\SampleTesting\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\c++\SampleTesting\main.c|20|warning: too few arguments for format|
C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\c++\SampleTesting\main.c|25|error: expected ')' before ';' token|
C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\c++\SampleTesting\main.c|27|error: expected ';' before '}' token|
C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\c++\SampleTesting\main.c|27|error: expected declaration or statement at end of input|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 1 warnings ===|

Comment: Since no one else called it out specifically, I'll mention you have another place where the quotes are wrong: `printf("option %c.\n, choice");` You shouldn't have enclosed `, choice` in those quotes

Answer (score 4):

The error is because of the missing `)` in `While` statement.

Currently it is:
`while ((choice != 's') && (choice != 'j') && (choice != 'm');`

it should be

`while ((choice != 's') && (choice != 'j') && (choice != 'm'));`

Apart from that you have issues with your `scanf` and `printf` statements.

Currently they are: 
`scanf(" %c, &choice");`

and

`printf("option %c.\n, choice");`

These should be changed to : 
`scanf(" %c", &choice);`

and

`printf("option %c.\n", choice);`

These type of issues can be easily avoided if taken care while writing the code.

Comment: Thanks, sshekhar!.. Are errors like this common when learning C?

Comment: These types of error are just typo and can be easily avoided if taken care while writing the code.

Answer (score 3):

You have several syntactical problems.

In your `scanf` line, the closing double quote is in the wrong place, it should be after `%c`.

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

In you `while` line, you are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the line.

```
} while ((choice != 's') && (choice != 'j') && (choice != 'm'));
```

Fixing both of these errors causes the program to compile and run fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
In function 'main':
Line 25: error: expected ')' before ';' token
Line 27: error: expected ';' before '}' token
Line 27: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

http://codepad.org/tXK1DlsJ

First of all, you don't close the braces of your do-while loop. You need to add the braces at the end.

```
while ((choice != 's') && (choice != 'j') && (choice != 'm'));
```

Additionally, as other people have mentioned you need to change your scanf statement to

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```